# NetLogo: Using turtles-own in multiple included files

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a model in NetLogo and **I would like to separate procedures in different files**, grouped by their purpose. I am doing so by writing that code in different files and using `__include["name_of_file_1.nls" "name_of_file_2.nls" ...]`.

As I would like it to be tidy as possible, I use `turtles-own[ ]` in each **included file**, declaring the variables that will be used in the procedures from that file. So, in case I'd like to modify the name of that variable or anything else, I would only need to go to that specific included file and modifying the variable in there. Instead of modifying it in the code tab and then switching to one of the included files.

But, if I work like this, **turtles won't own the variables declared in a file**. For example, I have all setup procedures defined in a file. When the setup button is clicked from the interface, `setup` recalls all procedures contained in the included file `setup_procedures.nls`. However, if after setting up, I inspect some of the turtles, they don't own the variables declared with `turtles-own[ ]` in the `setup_procedures.nls` file.

**Should I declare all variables in the code tab? Is there a way to make it work as I intended?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's been almost a year since I asked this question and it remains unanswered. From my experience this is because no, there is no way to declare turtle variables in multiple .nls files without getting some errors.

What has resulted more adequate to me is declaring all turtle variables in the `setup_procedures.nls` file and having all of them together in there. This eases having a clearer "Code" tab. The drawback is in case of having to rename a variable, this has to be done in more than one tab. Something which is quite fast to achieve trough `Edit > Find... > Replace With`, though.

I hope this can help anyone who ask themselves the same question i did!